# Is there a way to pod deintegrate but without deleting Pods folder?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I was wondering if there is a way to run `pod deintegrate` without it removing the `Pods` folder, just making the changes to *project.pbxproj* file?

Why do I ask this?

- In my company, everytime we have to push changes we do `pod deintegrate` so that the *project.pbxproj* pod installed changes doesn't go into the git repo. So doing so, it deletes Pods folder and I have to do `pod install` shortly after and since there are hundreds of pods this is time consuming.
- I don't have to do this everytime... mostly I just don't commit the *project.pbxproj* file on most of the PR's but whenever a file is added/moved/deleted in the project this is required

What is my goal?

- Is there a -tag or even some other script that applies the `pod deintegrate` changes into the *project.pbxproj* file? But without actually deleting the Pods folder? So I can save some time only to commit changes and without having to wait the whole `deintegrate` and `install` processes

Comment: I'm wondering if renaming the Pods Folder, doing pod reintegrate, rename to the "normal nam" the Pods Folder would do the trick for you.

Comment: That could actually work. I'm going to test that. if it woks I can create a script to do this automatically

Comment: @Larme if you want you can make your comment as an answer so i can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

1. Rename the `Pods` folder to something else
2. Run `pod deintegrate`, that
   will delete Pods folder, but since you've removed it, it won't.
3. Revert the renamed `Pods` Folder back to `Pods`

From there, a simple script might suffice to do it quicker.